# How to use bitwise AND in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, bitwise-operators

We have a FLAGS column in our DB which is used for storing various flags. This is a NUMBER column. The number will change depending upon the flags which are set. I want to select all the rows from a table for which  a particular flag is set. The flag can be obtained by doing a BITWISE AND on the column 'FLAGS' with the hex value: `0x0008000000000000L`.  How can I do it? I am a little new to Oracle SQL.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions014.htm#SQLRF00612

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select * from yourtable 
  where bitand(flags, to_number('8000000000000', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'))>0;
```

Answer (score 2):

PLSQL provides a function called `BITAND` for that

Use it like this

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE BITAND(FLAGS, TO_NUMBER('8000000000000', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx')) > 0
```

If you want to know more about BITAND take a look at this page https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/bitand.php

Comment: `= 8000000000000`  will not work... should be `= TO_NUMBER('8000000000000', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx')`, but since that is too verbose, I chose `>0` in my answer.

Comment: [`BITAND`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions014.htm) is SQL function, not a PL/SQL function. (It works in PL/SQL because PL/SQL supports most SQL functions.)